# How to attach the "NEW!" icon on a custom field

Tags: list, custom

I am working on Sharepoint 2010 and I have created a custom list. I set the default "Title" field as "hidden" and I am wondering how I can attach the "NEW" icon to a specific field for which I want to track the new records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a new display, usually with a data view web part.  Within the XSLT, you can add this code:

```
<xsl:if test="ddwrt:IfNew(string(@Created))">
    <img src="/_layouts/1033/images/new.gif" alt="New" />
</xsl:if>
```

Which will display the New! icon for you.

Reference: http://sharethelearning.blogspot.com/2007/06/how-to-display-new-icon-against-list.html